# Clarification on Python Syntax

Tags: python

I am new to learning python and am hoping to receive a little clarity.

If I have some python code that looks like the following:

```
for row in my_data:
        for w in row[1:]:
```

Is that essentially saying:

1. For each row in the my_data.csv
2. For each column, in the current row in the my_data.csv, starting at the second column (Column B)

I am trying to understand more directly what the syntax `row[1:]` means. I have not successfully found documentation that answers that.

Thanks.

Comment: You have interpreted both loops correctly. See the duplicate question to learn more about slice notation (i.e. `[1:]` part).

Comment: Thank you @Selcuk, I didn't know it was called 'slice' notation. I apologize for making a duplicate.

Comment: @JerryM. All good. Such questions are difficult to search online when you don't know the correct term.